App is getting values from wrong string.xml
I am facing a strange issue.
I have an Android application with 2 languages, en and el
The English values are stored in  values / strings.xml and the Greek  in values-el-rGR/ strings.xml
If you select Greek and reopen the application, Greek is the selected language and all the app details are in Greek.
But when I am choosing something from the list the app gets the string value from the default with the result in the next screen being empty


To mention that this happens only the first time when you open the app and the language is Greek.
If I go back to the main Activity and try again then is ok.
When the app starts at main activity I call loadLocale();
public void loadLocale (){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String languagestring = prefs.getString("My_Lang", "");
    languageSelection = languagestring;
    setLocale(languagestring);
}

private void setLocale (String lang){
    Locale locale = new Locale (lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
    editor.apply();
    if (lang.equals("el")){
        language.setImageResource(R.drawable.gr);

    }
    else if (lang.equals("en"))
    {
        language.setImageResource(R.drawable.eng);

    }
}

What I am doing wrong?

values-el would apply to all countries where you can select Greek as language, values-el-rGR only applies to you when selecting Greek as language and Greece as country/region. (like in en-US vs en-GB vs en-Canada/Australia/India/...). Would change that first of all. Updating app config is known to be problematic, not sure if there's an issue with locale changes like that. There's also https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages you could have a look at. Or you simply rely on the system language of the device. English is default whenever the language isn't supported

Thank you very much I will try what you provide
